# Showing last accessed / urldate field with babelbib

Tags: bibliographies, babel, urls

Apparently `babelbib` displays the `last accessed`/`urldate` field by default, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried to change the bibliographystyle, but that didn't fix it either. In addition I can't just change it to say `biblatex`, because the document class I'm using apparently has too many dependencies.

What I would like the bibliography to look like:

```
Wikipedia: Stackoverflow. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow, last accesed: 2014-02-17
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@misc{wiki:SO,
    Date-Added = {2014-02-25 20:50:43 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-02-26 09:05:39 +0000},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow}},
    Language = {english},
    Title = {Wikipedia: StackOverflow},
    Urldate = {2014-02-17},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{english}

\begin{document}

This page is about StackOverflow\cite{wiki:SO}.

{\bibliographystyle{plain}}
{\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}}

\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not explaind in the documentation, but in order for the `urldate` field to be used, the bib entry has to contain a `url` field.  So all you need to do is move your url from the `howpublished` field in to the `url` field.

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@misc{wiki:SO,
    Date-Added = {2014-02-25 20:50:43 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-02-26 09:05:39 +0000},
    url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow},
    Language = {english},
    Title = {Wikipedia: StackOverflow},
    Urldate = {2014-02-17},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{english}

\begin{document}

This page is about StackOverflow\cite{wiki:SO}.

\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}

\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

Incidentally your code contained two `\bibliographystyle` commands, meaning that the second one (the one you need!) is ignored.  I have removed the call to the `plain` style.

Comment: Ah! I actually had this in the beginning, but it didn't work. Now I just found out that `filecontents*` doesn't create a new file, when the same file already exists, therefore my bib file never got updated, when I tried out the `url` field. Thanks!